# Invoking a named function expression

Tags: javascript

Can I immediately call(invoke) a named function expression without a variable name like this?

```
var bookingMask = function (ac) {
....
}('.selectDates');
```

Comment: But I think mostly you want either of those no? It helps to know though!

Comment: There is no named function in your code. Can you clarify what you mean since the title of your question conflicts with the actual question

Comment: @slebetman is right, answers to this question reflect the problem too

Comment: Do you want the name `bookinMask` to be available after you execute it as an *IFFE*? If not @T.J. Crowder answer is what you need. Otherwise you should clarify.

Comment: It seems to me like you need a *statement* and an *expression* in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really mean "named" function expression, yes, you can do that:

```
(function bookingMask(ac) {
    // ...
})('.selectDates');
```

Note the `()` wrapping it. Otherwise, the `function` keyword would lead the parser to assume that it was the beginning of a function *declaration*, which you can't directly invoke in that way.

You might want that if you want to use `bookingMask` *inside* the function (e.g., recursion).

Live Example:

```js
(function bookingMask(ac) {
    console.log("ac is: " + ac);     // "ac is: .selectDates"
    console.log(typeof bookingMask); // "function"
})('.selectDates');
```

If you meant `bookingMask` to be the *result* of the call, you can do that too:

```
var bookingMask = (function nameForTheFunctionHere(ac) {
    // ...
})('.selectDates');
```

If you're doing that, since the parser is already expecting an expression as of the `function` keyword there, you don't need the wrapper `()`, this is fine:

```
var bookingMask = function nameForTheFunctionHere(ac) {
    // ...
}('.selectDates');
```

...but I tend to keep them anyway, since it's really easy when reading the code to miss the `(...)` at the end.

---

You can also do it without a name (just remove `bookingMask` above), but you did specifically say "named", so... :-)

---

*(If anyone's wondering why this answer has four downvotes, when I first posted an answer I missed the fact that the OP had mentioned a **named** function expression, not least because there isn't one in the question. A couple of people were kind enough to let me know so I could fix it. But people were initially voting on the incorrect answer.)*

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different ways of declaring a function, you can either use [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) or [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function). The 'expression' part means that it is either assigned to a value `var func = function cat(){}` or you use parentheses to tell the JavaScript engine to go get the value inside and evaluate it as an expression. So the name IFFE, immediately invoked function expression comes from first turning the function into an expression `(function(){})` then calling it `(function(){})()`.

So in your case, you do not want to evaluate the function 'assigning it to a variable' you want to create assign and run the function at once like so...

```
(function(ac) {
// code...
})('.selectDates');
```

If your feeling very adventurous you can also use other operators other than the parentheses to evaluate the IFFE such as;

```
+function IFFE(){

}()
```

```
-function IFFE(){

}()
```

Comment: There is only one way to declare a function, assignment of a function expression or an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) are not function declarations. ;-)

Comment: If you use a function name within the IFFE then you are still declaring a function.

Comment: No you aren't. A function expression, named or not, is not a function declaration.